# OnScrollChange(...) not called on horizontal scroll

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, onscrollchanged

I have a Xamarin.Forms App (XF 4.2.0.709249).

I have subclassed Scrollview and created a renderer for it in the Android Project.

I have overridden `OnScrollChanged` methods and hooked into multiple `scroll-changed-listeners` but **none of them get called when the scrollview is scrolled horizontally**.

I noticed that the [Xamarin.Forms ScrollViewRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ScrollViewRenderer.cs) for Android internally uses a `HorizontalScrollView` for horizontal scrolling, might this be missing an implementation to invoke the events/call the overridable methods?

EDIT: I also noticed, that setting an x-value in the renderers `ScrollTo(int x, int y)` method, does not have any effect on the X-Scrolling. `ScrollX` inside the renderer stays 0 forever, even tho the XamarinForms Scrolled event sends an updated X coordinate.

**Forms Project**

```
public class FormsScrollView : ScrollView { }

public class SomePage : ContentPage {
    public SomePage() {
        //calls native scroll events
        vertScrollView = new FormsScrollView() { Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical, Content = SomeScrollableContent };

        //never calls native scrollevents in renderer
        horizontalScrollView = new FormsScrollView() { Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal };
        horizontalScrollView.Content = CreateScrollContent(20, StackOrientation.Horizontal);
        Content = horizontalScrollView;
    }

    private StackLayout CreateScrollContent(int amount, StackOrientation ori)
    {
        var sl = new StackLayout() { Orientation = ori };
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            sl.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Cool Label " + i });
        return sl;
    }
}
```

**Android Project**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FormsScrollView), typeof(FormsScrollView_Droid))]
namespace Coolio.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class FormsScrollView_Droid: ScrollViewRenderer, Android.Views.View.IOnScrollChangeListener
    {
        private readonly IOnScrollChangeListener _scrollListener;

        public FormsScrollView_Droid(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _scrollListener = new ScrollListener(this);
            SetOnScrollChangeListener(this);
            SetOnScrollChangeListener(_scrollListener);


             this.ScrollX; //never changes, stays 0 forever
             this.ScrollTo(x, y); //setting x has no effect, however setting y does scroll vertically correctly.
        }

        protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
        {
              //never called on horizontal scroll
        }

        public void OnScrollChange(Android.Views.View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
        {
             //never called on horizontal scroll
        }
    }


    public class ScrollListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView.IOnScrollChangeListener
    {
        private readonly FormsScrollView_Droid _scrolli;

        public ScrollListener(FormsScrollView_Droid scrolli)
        {
            _scrolli = scrolli;
        }

        public void OnScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
        {
            //never called on horizontal scroll
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your layout in xamarin forms. I test it in my demo,I just put a `ScrollView`, `OnScrollChanged` and `OnScrollChange` was executed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I updated the layout of my XF Project sample, take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this thread:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62241/problem-setting-on-scroll-listener-to-android-horizontal-scroll-view-class-not-found-exception

I changed the `FormsScrollView_Droid` like following code.

```
 public class FormsScrollView_Droid: ScrollViewRenderer, ViewTreeObserver.IOnScrollChangedListener
{
   // private readonly IOnScrollChangeListener _scrollListener;

public FormsScrollView_Droid(Context context) : base(context)
{

        ViewTreeObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(this);

   // SetOnScrollChangeListener(_scrollListener);
}


protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
{
    //called on Vertical scroll
}

public void OnScrollChange(Android.Views.View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
{

}

  public void OnScrollChanged()
  {
       //called on Horizontal scroll
  }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: that looks promising! really cool gif to visualize it hits the breakpoint! I will test tonight, but I will still ask, in case you have the time: can you check if the "ScrollX" property ever changes? Preferrably inside the OnScrollChanged method

Comment: I indeed dont see any change in the ScrollX parameter of the ScrollViewRenderer. It's nice to see the onscrollchanged gets hit, but I have to extract the distance it has scrolled as well... do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok sorry for spam, thanks again for showing me the callback. Sadly ScrollViewRenderers `ScrollX` remains 0 and `ScrollTo(x, y)` does not affect the X-Axis-Scrolling. I would have to open another question for that.